# Class 'Observable<T>' defines instance member property 'select', but extended class 'Store<T>' defines it as instance member function

Tags: node.js, angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

Hi I just installed angular 4/5. And i was trying to use ngrx store. When i npm start, am getting the following error. Last when i worked on Angular 2 I didn't get this issue. I have went through many github discussions but not able to find a solution.

`ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store.d.ts:13:5 
    TS2425: Class 'Observable<T>' defines instance member property 'select', but extended class 'Store<T>' defines it as instance member function.`

the following is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "dishoo",
  "description": "Angular2",
  "main": "src/app/main.ts",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4.3",
    "npm": "~3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "webpack": "webpack --progress --profile --bail",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "clean": "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules dist dll-dist",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:dll": "npm run rimraf -- dll-dist",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "preclean:start": "npm run clean",
    "clean:start": "npm start",
    "build": "npm run build:dll && npm run build:dev",
    "prebuild:dll": "npm run clean:dll",
    "build:dll": "npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack/webpack.dll.js",
    "prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
    "build:dev": "npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack/webpack.dev.js",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch",
    "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --force"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ioat"
  ],
  "license": "dishoo",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^4.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^4.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^4.1.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.8.0",
    "angular-highcharts": "^4.0.7",
    "angular2-highlight-js": "^6.0.1-alpha",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^1.3.6",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bourbon": "^4.3.4",
    "bourbon-neat": "^1.9.0",
    "chalk": "^2.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highcharts": "^6.0.2",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.2",
    "moment": "^2.15.0",
    "ng2-data-table": "^1.0.0",
    "ng2-select": "^1.1.2",
    "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "npm-check-updates": "^2.13.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "vinyl-fs": "",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.43",
    "@types/highcharts": "^5.0.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.6.3",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.82",
    "@types/node": "8.0.50",
    "@types/protractor": "4.0.0",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.43",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.4",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.3.0",
    "codelyzer": "4.0.1",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "3.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.5",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.2.0",
    "node-neat": "^2.0.0-beta.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.2",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.13",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^3.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "precss": "^2.0.0",
    "protractor": "5.2.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.4",
    "string-replace-loader": "^1.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "2.2.0",
    "webpack-dashboard": "0.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.11",
    "webpack-merge": "0.17.0"
  }
}
```

Any idea guys? Do i need to provide anything else? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this???!!